# Plotting a .txt file, trouble converting string to float

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a .txt file of lines of the form: filename.txt,date,magnitude.

Ex: V098550.txt,362.0,3.34717962317

I am trying to plot the date against the magnitude.

I am new to coding and getting the message:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: V113573.txt,362.0,3.5425960309.

Do you know how I can fix this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

names = '/home/sindelj/research/condensed.txt'

for ii in range (len(names)):
    lc = np.loadtxt ("condensed.txt")
    plt.scatter (lc[:,0],lc[:,1])
    plt.xlabel ('Time')
    #take mean date 
    #date = []
    #date_all = numpy.mean(date)
    #plt.xlim ([date_all+1, date_all-1])
    plt.ylabel ('Mag')
    plt.ylim ([15.,14.])
    plt.show()# after test comment this out
    fileName = names[ii][:-3] + ".png"
    plt.savefig(fileName)

print "done"
```

Comment: you can skip the first column using `np.loadtxt ("condensed.txt", usecols=(1,2))`

Comment: @user128285 can you provide your comment as an answer, which can be accepted?

Answer (score 0):

According to [loadtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) docs you can specify which columns to load with `usecols` argument. Also `unpack` argument allows you to return data columnwise.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

names = '/home/sindelj/research/condensed.txt'

for ii in range (len(names)):
    x, y = np.loadtxt ("condensed.txt", usecols=(1, 2), unpack=True)
    plt.scatter (x, y)
    plt.xlabel ('Time')
    plt.ylabel ('Mag')
    plt.ylim ([15.,14.])
    plt.show() # after test comment this out
    fileName = names[ii][:-3] + ".png"
    plt.savefig(fileName)

print "done"
```